Imports suddenly stopped working in python
I was trying to make a discord bot. It was working fine upto this afternoon when I closed the editor for the day. But now when I opened it again, it is showing three warning flags (yellow squiggly lines) with "Import could not be resolved".
import os
import discord #not working
import inventory
from dotenv import load_dotenv #not working
from typing import Final
from discord.ext import commands #not working

(Note: I am using virtual environments to integrate google sheets in inventory.py)
I tried to reinstall the three imports which were not working. I hoped that this would make it realize that it was there. However command prompt just said "Requirement already satisfied" for all of the components and the code still threw the three warning flags.

Are/Were you using virtual environments by any chance?

Yes. The inventory class that is mentioned in the code uses them to access google sheets.

@DeepbortyProductions so, your code doesn't use a virtual environment, it doesn't make sense to say "the inventory class uses them".

What is discord.exe? Did you mean discord.ext? In addition, to be able to import dotenv, you first need to install the python-dotenv package.

@Hazzu Yes that was a typo, but only in the question. discord.ext is what is in the code. I do have python-dotenv installed

This could be the result of a few problems. First of all, this implies that your python language server does not have the packages installed. You said that when you reinstalled the packages it said they are already installed, therefore I assume your code looks for the wrong python version.
If you used a virtual environment (like venv for example) to setup your installed packages, then you probably need to activate it (run the activate script in the terminal you want to run your python code. On Windows its a .bat file, on Linux you can do source .../activate)
If you did not use a virtual environement, there can be multiple versions of python installed. Figure out which one you use when you install the packages and try to run your program with this version directly. Also, if your code is from a jupyter notebook, see if you selected the right python kernel.
Finally, you didn't say whether you tried running the problem. Did you get an error? If the program works just fine, then only the language server has a problem and it might be an issue with the IDE.
I hope this helps.
